# Referencing existing SWIG wrappers when creating new ones

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have an existing library (JPhysX) that is a Java wrapper for a native C++ library (PhysX). The Java library makes use of types generated by SWIG, for example, `com.jphysx.SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream`, which represents a pointer to an `NxStream` object in the C++ code. Now I want to create my own C++ class that inherits from the C++ type `NxStream`, and have the Java wrapper for my class also inherit from the wrapper `com.jphysx.SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream`.

The problem is that when I call SWIG to generate the wrapper for my class, it also creates a new wrapper called `SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream`, which is functionally identical to the one in `com.jphysx`, but still a different type as far as Java is concerned.

How can I convince SWIG to reuse this existing wrapper from `com.jphysx` and make the wrapper of my class inherit from `com.jphysx.SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the wrapper class explicitly inherit from the desired type did the trick in this case:

```
%typemap(javabase) UserStream "com.jphysx.SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream";
```

There were some methods in the wrapper class with which I had similar problems, but I simply removed them from the SWIG interface file because they aren't going to be called from the Java code anyway.

**Edit**: this does *not* work. Since the wrapper type inherits from another wrapper type, it suddenly has *two* `swigCPtr` fields. The one in the subtype is initialized, the one in the supertype remains `0`... but this is the one that gets used when you use the supertype somewhere.

**Edit 2**: I finally solved the problem, by adding a method to the Java wrapper class to convert the `UserStream` object to a `SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream` object:

```
%typemap(javacode) UserStream %{
    public native com.JPhysX.SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream toNxStreamPtr();
%}
```

This JNI method was hand-written outside SWIG's stuff:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_physics_UserStream_toNxStreamPtr(JNIEnv *env, jobject userStreamObject) {
    jclass userStreamClass = env->GetObjectClass(userStreamObject);
    jmethodID getCPtrMethodID = env->GetStaticMethodID(userStreamClass, "getCPtr", "(Lphysics/UserStream;)J");

    jlong cPtr = env->CallStaticLongMethod(userStreamClass, getCPtrMethodID, userStreamObject);
    jboolean futureUse = false;

    jclass nxStreamPtrClass = env->FindClass("com/JPhysX/SWIGTYPE_p_NxStream");
    jmethodID nxStreamPtrConstructor = env->GetMethodID(nxStreamPtrClass, "<init>", "(JZ)V");
    jobject nxStreamPtrObject = env->NewObject(nxStreamPtrClass, nxStreamPtrConstructor, cPtr, futureUse);
    return nxStreamPtrObject;
}
```